# What is difference between text-processing and text-formatting tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I found two similar tags on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site which are [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) and [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting). But I am little confuse to understand exactly which of them should be used when?

As both deals with Text processing/formatting utilities like: `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `cut`, `grep`, `diff`, `sort` etc. why both are exist?

Should one of them be synonyms of another?

Comment: Input and output

Answer (score 8):

I'm not really sure that we need both tags but there is a difference between [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) and [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing). First of all, yes, [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) is a subset of [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing). However, *formatting* refers to changing a file's format, not to extracting information from it.

For example, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209025/22222) is about text *formatting*. The OP has a file in a particular format and wants the same information but in a different format.

I would use [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) for extracting information from text files (parsing them) and [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) for manipulating the way that data from a text file are displayed. As a rule of thumb, if a subset of the information is to be extracted, use [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) and if only the format, the presentation of the data, is to be changed, use [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) (or both).

---

<sub>Please don't assume that this is site policy. This is just my personal take on these tags, feel free to downvote/disagree.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The way I understand the tag name [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) spontaneously is that it's about applying formatting to text, such as bold, italic, section titles, line and page breaks, etc.

The tag wiki gives a completely different meaning. I understand it as applying to *producing* text which has to be arranged in a particular way, as opposed to [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) which is about *reading* text and often, but not always producing modified text.

[text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) isn't on my mental radar, I wouldn't have thought of using it before seeing this meta thread. I'm not sure if I'll be remembering it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Text processing may involve additional filtering or 'rows'/'cells' transposition etc., which are more than just formatting the text differently from the source.

However, you might still be onto something. Since [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting) is created much more recently and is more narrow in scope, it may not be too far-fetched to think of it as a synonym to [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `text-processing` and `text-formatting` is that you might process a text into some other format, such as an image, or a page description (as in `pdf` or `ps`), while text formatting formats a text to produce another text in a special formatted way.

So roughly I would say, when you process a text the result might be have any format and encoding or even no visual result at all but some kind of system function, while when you format a text the source and destination formats are plain texts basically.

> As both deals with Text processing/formatting utilities like: sed, awk, perl, cut, grep, diff, sort etc. why both are exist?

All those tools are text formatting tools, while text processing tools are `tex`, `roff`, `metapost`, `gs`.

Of course `text-formatting` tools are often used to format text for further processing.